# G Cloud says I have thousands of pictures and data but I cannot find anything when I log into my g cloud account. No Buckets either

Tags: video, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-photos, android-backup-service

I received this email....

Your account has expired! Don’t lose your Photos and Videos.
You have backed up 5535 photos and 536 videos on G Cloud!
Renew your subscription now and don’t lose your precious memories.
You can get 17% OFF all annual plans in the app, download now and save your files.
Your expired account will be deleted in 7 days.

I have logged into my g cloud and there is nothing there.  Is it referring to another
are that I am unaware of?

I also have 100GB account on google drive.

Can I backup phones to either place?
Do they communicate with each other as a single data storage area?

Does google have any type of support for users!

I am on limited time to download this information but cannot find it.

Mark

I logged in...  went to cloud storage...  there were NO projects...
so there were no buckets...   I created a project....  still no storage information.

What am I doing wrong?

Mark

Comment: Show the exact wording in the email.  Check if you have a Google One account. Check your Google Drive account.  1) Google Cloud does not use the term `G Cloud` to describe its services. 2) Google Cloud Storage does not have subscriptions. You have either misread the email, the email is from a different vendor or you have a SPAM email. Usually, renewal emails have a resubscribe link. What is that link? Before clicking it, make sure it is a real Google URL.